# how to create a calculated fields programmatically

Tags: column, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, xml, splist

I need  to create a calculated item , which has: the ID of the item, the created date and title.
How to do this combination in xml.
i tried this code :

```
<Field Type="Calculated"  DisplayName="$Resources:SiteColumns,Calculated_Title" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" 
         Format="DateOnly" LCID="1033" ResultType="Text" ReadOnly="TRUE" ID="{bc7b5078-a90d-47e3-b0fc-8d87c0a0721d}" 
         SourceID="{d10a9f52-13ca-4392-9f51-c0f25b0b929a}" StaticName="Calculated_Title" Name="Calculated_Title"  ColName="sql_variant1" RowOrdinal="0" Required="FALSE" Version="13">
    <Formula>=Title&amp;" num : "&amp;ID&amp;" créer a "&amp;TEXT(Created,"d-mmm-yyyy  hh:ss")</Formula>
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef Name="Created" />
      <FieldRef Name="ID" />
      <FieldRef Name="Title" />
    </FieldRefs>
  </Field>
```

it doesnt work with visual studio.

but if i use the OOB,with this fomula it works fine 
the formular :

```
=Title&" num : "&ID&" créer a "&TEXT(Created,"d-mmm-yyyy  hh:ss")
```

so how to do it to have a programmaticaly calcualted filed, with correct formula using the XML.

Comment: Can you try Author instead CreatedBy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not write the ID field, it is set by SharePoint **after** the Item is created in the SQL server database